# App Store Export Compliance - does this include data stored in keychain?

Tags: ios, app-store

Rather confused about this.

I'm storing the user's username and password inside Keychain in my app, does this constitute an encryption feature in accordance to the App Store Export Compliance? Or does this concern things like SSL?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I submitted the app without ticking the box for encryption data and it was accepted. It seems that keychain does not effect this.

Comment: It is explicitly stated by Apple that complying to EAR is your legal responsibility. https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev88f5c7bf9 So, the fact that an app is accepted to App Store does not necessarily mean that keychain is an exception to EAR.